# Unity 5 Camera orthographic size not changing

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to change camera's orthographic size with code or animation. For example, when I change it to 100, nothing happens only Camera component on Main camera shows Size 100, but size is not changing on Game Tab or Scene Tab. However when I click anything on Camera component like Allow HDR, Allow MSAA or changing values manually, size is changing on Game Tab and Scene Tab. I have no idea what to do. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you include your version of Unity?  And show us how you are changing the camera size in code?

Comment: @AresCaelum Unity version: 3.0f2      this is my code `Camera.main.orthographicSize = 100;` I call it on update() and Start(). Problem is on editor Camera component's size value is changing and shows size is 100, but camera size is not changing on gameplay.

Comment: Does it change if you click with the mouse in the GameView?

Comment: @derHugo When game is running if I click anything with mouse ofc on camera component yes it changes. For example, size shows 100 but it's not, but if I change size with mouse manually when game is running camera size changes in the GameView.

Comment: This is my code again:  `Camera.main.orthographicSize = 20;` This is GameView: ![Size show 20 but still 8](https://imge.to/i/vIMqCw). However if I click anything on Camera Component like Allow HDR or Allow MSAA or click size values with mouse camera size changes: ![Size 20 in the GameView](https://imge.to/i/vIMjIT).

Comment: Version 2019.3.0f2?

Comment: No Version 2018.3.0f2

Comment: What you show us is the Scene view not the GameView .. my question is does it update if you focus on the GameView not the Camera component? Like click anywhere inside the GameView?

Comment: No, it doesn’t change.

Comment: Unfortunately your screenshots aren't very useful,  I see the scene view, not the game view in your screenshots.  There is also no screenshots of the game view before and after your view changes.

Comment: Ok here is my game views. This is code : `Camera.main.orthographicSize = 13;` ![Camera before clicking Allow HDR](https://imge.to/i/vTU2Li).  ![Camera after clicking Allow HDR](https://imge.to/i/vTUBOV). Both components say camera size  is 13 but after clicking anything on Camera component size is changing int the Game View.